# Wrapping getServerSideProps throws exception

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am trying to wrap `getServersideProps` with auth handler function, but keep getting this error:
`TypeError: getServerSideProps is not a function`
my wrapper looks like this:

```
export async function protect(gssp) {
    return async (context) => {
        const {req, res} = context;
        const auth = await authHandler(req);
        if (!auth.authenticated) {
            res.statusCode = 302;
            res.setHeader('Location', '/');
            return;
        }
        context.auth = auth;
        return await gssp(context);
    }
}
```

and on the page, getServerSideProps looks like this:

```
export const getServerSideProps = protect(async function(context) {
    return {
        props: {
            auth: context.auth
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The call `protect(...)` actually returns a promise, rather than a function, since you explicitly declared it as `async`. To fix the issue you can simply remove the async from that function.

```js
export function protect(gssp) {
    // Remaining code untouched
}
```